# regular expression (four-choice-three logic with regular)

Tags: javascript, regex

#### Password requirements:

The password must contain three types of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and special characters, and the length is between 8-30 characters. Password cannot contain 'administrator' string

#### The regularity I wrote

`/^(?![a-zA-Z]+$)(?![A-Z0-9]+$)(?![A-Z._~!@#$^&*]+$)(?![a-z0-9]+$)(?![a-z._~!@#$^&*]+$)(?![0-9._~!@#$^&*]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9._~!@#$^&*]{8,20}$/`
Obviously wrong.

*I don't know how to describe the four-choice-three logic with regular.Need Help.*

Comment: How do you define a "special" character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a single regex for this, it'll be way too complicated, since you'll have to write out each possible 3-combination of the 4 options, and alternate between each combination with `|`. Split each test into a single regex, then check how many tests pass programatically:

```
const test = (str) => {
  const hasUpper = /[A-Z]/.test(str);
  const hasLower = /[a-z]/.test(str);
  const hasNumbers = /\d/.test(str);
  const hasSpecial = /[._~!@#$^&*]/.test(str);
  if (hasUpper + hasLower + hasNumbers + hasSpecial < 3) {
    return false;
  }
  if (str.toLowerCase().includes('administrator')) {
    return false;
  }
  return str.length >= 8 && str.length <= 30;
};
```

If you also want to make sure that no characters *other* than those described exist in the string, then:

```
const hasOther = /[^a-z\d._~!@#$^&*]/i.test(str);
if (hasOther) {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let reg =/^(?![a-zA-Z]+$)(?![A-Z0-9]+$)(?![A-Z\W_!@#$%^&*`~()-+=]+$)(?![a-z0-9]+$)(?![a-z\W_!@#$%^&*`~()-+=]+$)(?![0-9\W_!@#$%^&*`~()-+=]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9\W_!@#$%^&*`~()-+=]{8,30}$/;
if(!reg.test(str) || str.toLowerCase().includes('administrator')){
  return false;
}
```